# How to check if image file exists on given url in local machine using python

Tags: python, django

I want to check image is existing on the given path. Code snippet as follows:

```
if the image exists:
   #business logic
else:
   #set default logo
```

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: you can follow this link. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-whether-a-file-exists-without-exceptions)
let me know if this answer your question?

Answer (score 5):

The most common way to check for the existence of a file in Python is using the exists() and isfile() methods from the os.path module in the standard library.

- Using exists:

  ```
  import os.path
  if os.path.exists('mydirectory/myfile.png'):
     #business logic
  else:
     #set default logo
  ```

  `os.path.exists('mydirectory/myfile.png')` returns True if found else
  False
- Using isfile:

  ```
  import os.path
  if os.path.isfile('mydirectory/myfile.png'):
     #business logic
  else:
     #set default logo
  ```

  `os.path.exists('mydirectory/myfile.png')` returns True if found else
  False
- Alternatively you can also use try-except as shown below:

  ```
  try:
      f = open('myfile.png')
      f.close()
  except FileNotFoundError:
      print('File does not exist')
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the `os.path.exists()` function in python. So it would be something like -

```
if os.path.exists('yourdirectory/yourfile.png'):
     #business logic
else:
    #set default logo
```

You can also use `os.path.isfile()` in a similar manner to check if it is a valid file (`os.paath.exists()` will return `True` for valid folders as well)